# Creating Symfony Application doesn't work

Tags: php, symfony

When I create a new symfony application with the command "symfony new --webapp app", in the repository src, I don't have the controller repository nor the kernel.php.
During the installation and after, I don't have error messages.

I always created my projects like that without problems. It's why I don't understand what happens.

- PHP version : 8.1.8
- Symfony version : 6.2

I also tried the command

```
composer create-project symfony/skeleton:"6.2.*" my_project_directory
```

but the problem is the same. I've also checked

```
symfony check:requirements
```

And according to this everything isfine.

And naturally, when I wanted to create a controller, the console tells me the class kernel was not found.

Comment: Could you share the output of any of the command you shared ? Looks like the **FrameworkBundle** recipe was not executed.

Comment: When I tried the command to create a controller the answer was : D:\00 - FORMATIONS\00 - formation DEV\03 - Symfony\UX TURBO\turbo>symfony console make:controller
Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Error\ClassNotFoundError^ {#38
  #message: """
    Attempted to load class "Kernel" from namespace "App".\n
    Did you forget a "use" statement for "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel"?
    """

Comment: Please edit your question to add code, it is impossible to read in comments. I'm not asking for the controller creation command but for the application creation command (`symfony new` or `composer create-project`). Because if something is wrong happens, it's during the application creation.

Comment: @SébastienMARIETTE I think there may be a language barrier here.  You seem to be saying that after creating your app, `app/src/Kernel.php` does not exist?  And that absolutely no errors were reported?  That just seems very unlikely.  You did cd to your app directory before running `bin/console make:controller`?  Actually, looking at your error message, I suspect that you did not.

Comment: I did cd to my app directory before making my controller.

Comment: Today everything is ok. I don't understand what the problem was. Thanks.